# How long does it take to resize an SD card?

Tags: sd-card

What are estimated times taken for resizing an SD card? I have a 32G card and it seems to be taking extra-long (over two hours waiting now)

Comment: While two hours seems a little long. Let it run. If I were you I would let it run overnight if need be before pulling the plug. Removing the power while it is resizing the disk  will likely require you to restart the process from the beginning.

Comment: Mine took just a few seconds. It was a Patriot LX

Comment: @gnibbler: How big was your card?

Comment: @ohblahitsme, 32GB. I also have an 8GB which was also quick.

Comment: I presume you're resizing the filesystem on a card. You can't resize a card. Growing it should be quick. Can you see the process in top? Anything suspicious in dmesg? You could even strace it to see what it's doing :)

Comment: What command have you run?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: the RPi ran its own magical command at (re)bootup.

Comment: @JohnSmith Ahhh yes...

Comment: @AlexChamberlain, mine was done natively on the RPi after the first boot by running `raspi-config`

Comment: It does appear that this is taking **much** longer than it should. One option is that the card *might* be a fake. Typically fakes report one capacity, but are actually much smaller and run at a fraction of the speed. I never trust what a card says its capacity it, and always run [h2testw](http://www.heise.de/download/h2testw.html) on my Windows box before I use *any* new memory card, even well respected brands. Another option is that the contacts may be dirty, causing poor data communications with the card and lots of retries. Try removing, cleaning the card and socket, then trying again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resized my 16GB class 10 SanDisk card, and it only took a few minutes.  I resized the root partition to fill the card with the gparted GUI on my laptop, rather than my RPi (like PhonicUK, I think).

Answer (score 4):

Depends on the size of the card, how fast it is and how good the reader is.

I did a resize on a 16GB Class 6 card and that took about 35 minutes all in all. I did it using gparted on a laptop instead of on the device itself (which I would imagine would be very slow)

Answer (score 1):

I resized a 32GB Class 10 card from `raspi-config`, and it took about five minutes.

Answer (score 0):

My experience: About 10 minutes, using the raspi-config on the Raspberry Pi itself with at 16GB Class 10 card.